# phrase or theory that describes "if he can do it then so can I"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context, phrase-requests, adjectives

What is the phrase or psychological term that describes someone who gains confidence based off of another's performance? Moreover, they use it as a motivational foundation and it relates to behavioral confirmation/self-efficacy.

--Example--

Alex Smith:"Bro, you should register for the Ironman Lanzarote in Spain next week."

Colin Kaepernick:"No way. That's deemed one of the top ten hardest triathlons on Earth."

Alex:"Joe's baby brother is in mediocre at best shape and was able to complete it easily last year."

Colin:"What!? Man, if he can do it then I sure as hell can do it."

Alex:"I'm just kidding but that confidence you just suddenly acquired is called ________."

Comment: I don't think there is a single word for that but I suggest *" If he can, I can"*

Comment: *Confident* would fit the description (Or "having confidence in one's own ability").

Comment: For one word, I would choose "mimic."

Comment: Well, as *mimic* and *confident* are so different, the question is unclear. @Long, please read the [tag info for SWR](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) so you can enhance your question to make clear exactly what you need here.

Comment: Arguably you would describe such a person as ***lacking in confidence, timid, unsure, weak*** if they're so uncertain of their own ability that they need to see that someone else (of equal or lesser ability) can do it before believing they can do it themselves. Effectively, they're exhibiting "confidence by proxy".

Comment: It appears to be a variant of [Annie Oakley Thinking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO23WBji_Z0).

Answer (score 1):

In a competitive context, you might call it [one-upmanship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-upmanship). If you're referring to the person doing it for social acceptance *just because* his friend(s) did it, it's [peer pressure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peer-pressure).

Without the social acceptance aspect, we simply have the neutral term [**peer influence**](http://sdtheory.s3.amazonaws.com/SDT/documents/2011_Joesaaretal_PSE.pdf). Here's [a paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-8624.00338/abstract) on it from a web search.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using ***self-believer***. It comes from the noun [***self-belief***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-belief) which means:

> ***confidence in oneself and one's ability***: *I have a lot of self-belief and if I receive a negative remark I use it to motivate myself*.

[Collins Online Dictionary]

A self-believer is someone who is confident in his/her ability.