# Is there an expression for the positive influence an elitist society can have on individuals?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary

Is there a sentence (or expression) in English that describes the positive effect (or influence) an elitist community can have on an individual?

To be more specific, let's take as an example an average student who just went to a top-school and end up pushing himself/herself to the limit to catch up with the rest of the class. Eventually, his/her grades go up as a result of the competition inside that class.

Comment: Would the idea be a community "struggle"?

Comment: @J.Taylor Yes, but not only that. It also includes a good thing that is ubiquitous in a community and becomes the social norm (e.g neighborhood watch).

Comment: Your question needs some more detail I think, for you to get helpful answers. Please look at the info on the tags to see if they are appropriate and if you have complied with then. eg *To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word*

Comment: @Spagirl I've just edited it, I'm not sure if I can be more specific (let me know if its conform to the rules.

Comment: @h4k1m I think it is still unclear and will be helped if you include a sample sentence which demonstrates how the word will be used... by this we mean a sentence where you have left a gap where the word/phrase itself would go. The whole could still be clearer, I'm not sure if you mean a community being supportive to an individual, a community having clear rules and roles for individuals or a community punishing anyone who steps out of line.

Comment: @Lawrence I've just updated the title.

Comment: @Spagirl I hope the example I've added has made my question clearer.

Comment: It looks like a positive version of [peer pressure / peer influence](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/304090/142322).

Comment: @h4k1m You still haven't given us an example sentence into which the word/phrase would be inserted. It is still not clear to me, perhaps it is to others, whether you are looking for something that describes the *influence* or its *effect*, are you looking for the *cause* or the *outcome* or are you seeking something which encapsulates both together?

Comment: @Spagirl I don't think I'll be able to come up with a sentence because it's just a abstract concept I was thinking about. Regarding your question, I would say the latter (something that encapsulates the cause and the effect).

Comment: @Lawrence `peer pressure` is close to what I'm looking for. Is there an equivalent for the pressure coming from the community in general (something like the `social contract`)?

Comment: @h4k1m Social norms?

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you. It seems like an acceptable answer, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @h4k1m Ok, done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the gist of the question has been changed multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call them *social norms*.

> - Social Norms are unwritten rules about how to behave.  They provide us with an expected idea of how to behave in a particular social group or culture.  For example we expect students to arrive to lesson on time and complete their work.
>   [- Saul McLeod, Simply Psychology](http://www.simplypsychology.org/social-roles.html)
> - Social norms, the customary rules that govern behavior in groups and societies, have been extensively studied in the social sciences.
>   [- Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/social-norms/)

It is a form of peer pressure. Where the group is of the elite (in a positive sense), its norms are likely to exert a positive influence on each individual within the group.